# decodeURI in java

Tags: javascript, java, urlencode

I want to decode this uri in java:

```java
URLDecoder.decode("/demo/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87/test%3Fa%3Da", UtilConst.UTF8);
// return "/demo/中文/test?a=a"
```

This is not my expected result, since it change the uri structure。I want to get the same result like JavaScript `decodeURI` method:

```js
decodeURI('/demo/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87/test%3Fa%3Da');
// return "/demo/中文/test%3Fa%3Da"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure there is an exact equivalent in Java. You could try implementing the algorithm from the ECMAScript spec (https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-decodeuri-encodeduri), but it would be a bit of work.

Comment: If you are generating the encoded URI in JavaScript yourself, try switching to encodeURIComponent. That should return an encoded string that URLDecoder can decode.

Comment: I think you are trying to get a string to do things that a string alone cannot do.  A string alone cannot distinguish between a `?` that’s a part of a URI’s path and a `?` that separates the path from the query.  That’s what the [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) class is for.

Answer (score -1):

```java
String url = "/demo/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87/test%3Fa%3Da";
StringJoiner decoded = new StringJoiner("/");

String[] splittedUrl = url.split("/");
for (String item : splittedUrl) {
    if (!item.startsWith("%")) {
        decoded.add(item);
    } else {
        decoded.add(URLDecoder.decode(item, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
System.out.println(decoded); // /demo/中文/test%3Fa%3Da
```

Comment: What I need is The Java code to decode uri like JavaScript `decodeURI` method

Comment: The desired code is in Java, not JavaScript. Please reread the question.

Comment: @xiaoxiyao sorry for misunderstanding i edited answer